# Get environment variables from a remote server

Tags: java, ssh

Is there a way in Java to get an environment variable from a remote server? 
I am currently executing:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { 
     "ssh", "myuser@myserver", "source myenvfile; echo $MY_VAR" 
});
```

<strike>But it returns blank (although my variable should contain something).</strike>

<strike>I get a result for commands such as `df` but none for `echo`. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?</strike>

**EDIT :** Does anyone have a better solution that this to do so ?

**NB:** I want to avoid the use of a SSH library.

Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: It looks like `myenvfile` is not in the remote user's `$HOME`, otherwise it should work

Comment: Actually, I just observed that it works... Please whip me... 
Anyway, if anyone has a better solution, I would enjoy seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a better solution: using a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` has [quite a few problems](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) which make it not really suitable for process execution.